# form validation with django CBV FormView

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

Can someone explain me how can I validate my form, it's rather simple stuff and some how I can I just don't get it, need to validate my select field so I can return and display data, can someone explain how to do this

```
from django import forms
from statistics.choices import MONTH_CHOICES


class StatisticsForm(forms.Form):
    invoice_year = forms.CharField(max_length=255, required=False,
                                      widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Search Year'}))
    month_choice = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MONTH_CHOICES)
```

Comment: Validation is performed in the form class, not the view class.

Comment: (facepalm), let me update my question

Comment: What do you need to check?

Comment: What do you mean by that? The form is automatically cleaned/validated according to the fields' default rules.

Comment: @TomasWalch, I just realize that this is not the case that I wanted to address, I need to check my `view` something is wrong there

Answer (score 0):

```
from django import forms
from statistics.choices import MONTH_CHOICES


class StatisticsForm(forms.Form): 
    invoice_year = forms.CharField(max_length=255, required=False,
                                  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Search Year'}))
    month_choice = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MONTH_CHOICES)

    def clean_invoice_year(self):
        invoice_year_val = self.cleaned_data.get('invoice_year')
        if condition_not_satisfied:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Invalid invoice year')
        return invoice_year_val
```